# Kindle's charging damaged, can I reuse with RPI

Tags: pi-zero-w

I have a kindle but microusb got damaged. I opened and tried to repair microusb but it resulted in more damage to the circuit connected to microusb.  I don't think I can charge the battery anymore.
Is it possible to use the kindle? let us say, charge the battery li-ion separately or use Pi to do some creative use of the display? don't feel like leaving it unused. Repairing the micro-usb is 5 time expensive than buying a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome, TBH this is a Pi support forum rather than a Kindle one but I’ve used both for a while so here goes a few electrons to try and help you.

Without knowing the driver and how it works you will find it very very hard to control the kindle screen as each e-ink will need specific voltage and timings.

You maybe able to jury-rig a connector and charger for the battery but you maybe stuck for space and even max charge details for the battery (and it’s never good to overcharge batteries - they can go bang and go up in flames).

The closest I have seen are software hacks for the Kindle and Nook but there are some hardware hacks on [Hackaday](https://hackaday.com/category/kindle-hacks/).